# Pandas return 1 or 0 when compared to another column's mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to create a new column that returns a 1 or a 0.  The logic is if the state's `['Avg_Temp']` is greater than or equal to the `['Avg_Temp'].mean()` then I want the `['Hot']` column to have the value of `1`, otherwise it should have the value of `0`.

My attempt is below but my results for `df['Hot']` are all `1` so I know I'm doing something wrong.

Data:

```
    Avg_Temp
MI  66          
AL  78
OH  50
VT  64
NB  34

df = data
TempMean = df10['Avg_Temp'].mean()
df10['Hot'] = 0
df10['Hot'] = df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1
return df10['Hot']
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code, for instance the indentation. Edit the question so it's ore clear. As it stands, there is confusion between what is `df` and what is `df10`. `df10` is never defined.

Comment: This may be enough: `df10['Hot'][df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1`. Notice how you have essentially two assignments in the penultimate line.

Comment: @Evert: chained assignment like that should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in this line:

```
df10['Hot'] = df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1
```

What `df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1` means is: "set 1 to the rows matching the condition". Then you assign the result of this operation to the column `Hot`. What you want to do is to replace that line with:

```
df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean, 'Hot'] = 1
```

Comment: I used the shorter, simpler of the two and it solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`df10['Hot'] = df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1`

doesn't do what you're intending.  It's equivalent here to

```
df10.loc[df10['Avg_Temp'] >= TempMean] = 1
df10['Hot'] = 1
```

which first sets every row with the Avg_Temp column >= TempMean to 1, and then sets the Hot column to 1.

You probably want

```
In [51]: df10["Hot"] = 0

In [52]: df10.loc[df10["Avg_Temp"] >= TempMean, "Hot"] = 1

In [53]: df10
Out[53]: 
    Avg_Temp  Hot
MI        66    1
AL        78    1
OH        50    0
VT        64    1
NB        34    0
```

or, simpler,

```
df10["Hot"] = (df10["Avg_Temp"] >= TempMean).astype(int)
```

where we wouldn't have to set `df10["Hot"]` first.

Answer (score 1):

I like

```
avg = df.Avg_Temp
df.assign(Hot=avg.ge(avg.mean()).astype(np.uint8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['Hot'] = np.where((df['Avg_Temp'] > df['Avg_Temp'].mean()), 1, 0)
```